# HTML form and Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem with HTML form and Jquery.

The simplified version looks like this:

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="send" name="send">
<textarea name="resp" cols="25" class="resp" rows="3"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="send" class="fsend" />
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("form#send").submit(function() {
var rs= $('.resp').attr('value');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "?a=up",
data: "rs="+ rs,
success: function(){
$(".<?=$pid;?>").text('ok').addClass('pzd');
$(".<?=$td;?>").hide();
}

});
return false;
});
});
```

The problem that I have with this form and Jquery code is that the ajax post always the same value of texterea. How can I empty or clear the textarea after sending data to PHP file using ajax and than be ready to input new data in textarea?

I tried using `document.send.resp.value = '';` , `send.resetForm();` `$(".resp").val('')` and many others, in on out of ajax success function...and without result.

Any help?

Comment: Did any of the below help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get why this doesn't work for you...

```
$('.resp').val('');
```

Works fine when I tried it.

See here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/d7zX6/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a jquery plugin which can handle your ajax requests very easy.
http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
$(':input','#send')
.val('');
```

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @andrewsi Thanks, I'll go two years back in time and let myself know.